# wp_nav_menu not working on category pages on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I created a couple of custom menus on wordpress using the appearance menu.

I want to display the right menu according to the page that I'm viewing. I wrote the script below in the header.php file in the seems to be working fine. It's pulling the correct menu according to the page that I'm visiting with the exception of the category pages.

When I'm on a category page, the wp_nav_menu function falls back to the fallback function, indicating that the menu doesn't exist?!

I was looking around and the solution that kept coming up was adding the following code but it doesnt seem to work.

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu('container_class=menu-header&theme_location=primary'); 
?>
```

Here is the full code that I added to the header.php file:

```
<?php
switch( $master_page ) {
    case 'about':
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu'  => 'about',
            'fallback_cb' => 'get_cat',
        )); 
    break;
    case 'offer':
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu'  => 'offer',
            'fallback_cb' => 'get_cat',
        )); 
    break;
}
?>
```

I'm really frustrated at this point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are assigning a value to `$master_page`, so at this point it is just an empty variable.

You need to look into the [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) and [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) functions in WordPress and use `if` statements rather than a `switch`.

```
<?php 
if( is_page( 'about' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu(array(
       'menu'  => 'about',
       'fallback_cb' => 'get_cat',
    ));
} else {
    ...
}
?>
```